# Core Plot - reversed plot and labels

Tags: objective-c, plot, core-plot

I have a problem with displaying the correct plot. I used some code from RealTimePlot (http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/RealTimePlot.m). I do not know why the plot is reversed. There is a photo showing the problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self generateDataSamples];

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:hostingView];

    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;


    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];

    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 15;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 40;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 15;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 55;

    // Grid line styles
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.2] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25;
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1]; 

    // Axes
    // X axis
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
    x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    x.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
    x.title = @"X Axis";
    x.titleOffset = 35.0;
    NSNumberFormatter *labelFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    labelFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;
    x.labelFormatter = labelFormatter;
    [labelFormatter release];

    // Y axis
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0);
    y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    y.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 3;
    y.labelOffset = 5.0;
    y.title = @"Y Axis";
    y.titleOffset = 30.0;
    y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

    // Rotate the labels by 45 degrees, just to show it can be done.
    //x.labelRotation = M_PI * 0.25;

    // Create the plot
    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = kPlotIdentifier;
    dataSourceLinePlot.cachePrecision = CPTPlotCachePrecisionDouble;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0;
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];

    // Plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(kMaxDataPoints - 1)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(250)];
}
```

[image: reversed plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS `CPTGraphHostingView` applies a flip transform to the hosted graph so Core Plot can share drawing code between iOS and the Mac. Make sure the hosting view and all of its superviews are using their default transforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The core plot graph was hosted in CPTGraphHostingView. I changed to UIView and now it is ok. Maybe could you help me with refreshing plot with real-time data? There is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869179/core-plot-realtime-plot-does-not-automatically-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
[hostingView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1)];
```

just before adding hostingView to self.view.

I use Xcode 5.0 for iOS7 and this solved the problem.